# submit() method does not work when call in input file changed

Tags: javascript

I have a simple form contain an input file for uploading file. now I want whenever user select a file , form submitted automatically . this is my html codes :

```
<form action="/upload" id="upload_form" name="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="user_file" id="user_file">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Form">
</form>
```

And this is javascript codes:

```
const upload_form = document.getElementById('upload_form')
const user_file = document.getElementById('user_file')

upload_form.addEventListener('submit',e=>{
    alert('Form Submitted...')

    e.preventDefault()
})
user_file.addEventListener('change', () => {
    alert('user file changed...')
    upload_form.submit()
})
```

Note that when I use Submit button to send form **Form Submitted...** is shown but that not work after input file is changed.

Comment: _"does not work"_ is not sufficient detail.  What happened when you tried?  Did you get an error?  What behaviour are you expecting?  What behaviour did you observe?

Comment: in fact `Form Submitted...` message does not show. that means whole of callback function that I take to submit does not run

Comment: So the form does submit, it's just that the submit event listener doesn't get triggered. That is the expected behaviour.

Comment: ok how can I solve the problem ?

Comment: When does your code run?If it runs before the DOM loads, then those elements don't exist and you can't add event listeners to them.

Comment: those run after DOM loads. because I inserted script tag at the end html file

Comment: see the [docs on submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit). `submit()` does not raise a submit event, however, you can call `requestSubmit()` instead which will have the same effect as clicking the form button

Comment: Yes , that's right...